# Storing multiple images in MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, mysqli

I am new to PHP.

I am trying to add multiple images with text to a database and I'm stuck. If I select one, it gets stored. If I select multiple, it's left as blank in the database.

I need help to resolve this. Plus, I am confused: is one table for images in db ok? I mean, is there a special datatype or way to have multiple images on the same entry in a database?

Here's my code:

```php
<html>
<body>
    <form class="container" enctype ='multipart/form-data' action="add.php" method="post">
        <label><b> Name: </b></label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        <label><b> Type: </b></label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="type"><br><br>
        <label><b> Detail: </b></label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="detail"><br><br>
        <label><b> Area: </b></label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="area"><br><br>

        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="filename" size='10000' multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
    </form>
    <?php
        // error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        require_once 'login.php';

        $db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
        if (!$db_server) die("unable to connect to mysqli:" . mysqli_error());

        mysqli_select_db($db_server, "dbase1") or die("db not selected" . mysqli_error());

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $type = $_POST["type"];
        $detail = $_POST["detail"];
        $area = $_POST["area"];

        if($_FILES)
        {
            $namee = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $namee);
            echo "uploaded image'$namee'<br><img src ='$namee'>";
        }

        $source= "pictures/".$namee;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO adprop (name, type, text,area,filename) VALUES ('$name','$type','$detail','$area','$source')";
        $db = $db_server->query($sql);
    ?>
</body>
<html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can save multiple image paths with writing them via comma in your tables's field. And split them in user interface.

Comment: can you show it on code i am freeze thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want save multiple image paths in a field, you can add them to db as below:

```
/image_folder/image_name1.jpg,/image_folder/image_name2.jpg
```

And use `split` and `for loop` to print them dynamically in user interface.

Comment: can you please edit this code for me i tried but felt quite dumb if you edit code i will really be thankful